# Multiple integral related to zeta function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, special-functions, riemann-zeta

I am trying to calculate the following integral
$$\int_V \frac{d^d\vec{r}}{e^{x_1+...+x_d}-1},$$
where $V=[0,\infty)^d$ and $\vec{r}=(x_1,...,x_d)$. I know that the result should be related to the Riemann zeta function, but I do not see how to do it quickly and elementary (i.e. without the knowledge of all possible relations for zeta function). Any sugestion or hint ?

Comment: Just a question. The integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{e^x-1}dx$ is divergent while $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx$ ($n\ge 1$) is not and, for even $n$, yields the zeta function. How is all this consistent with your integral?

Comment: Right. My integral follows from statistical physics and as I checked, from physical reasons, I should assume that $d$ is at least $2$. Maybe it is not enough for this integral to be finite, but it is the only restriction on $d$ which I can find now. If this integral would convergent only for some $d$'s it would be also an interesting result.

Comment: For d=2 it seems to evaluate to $\pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)^d}\frac{x_1}{e^{x_1+\ldots+x_d}-1}\,d\mu_d = \int_{(0,+\infty)^{d-1}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x_1}{e^{x_1+\ldots+x_d}-1}\,dx_1\,d\mu_{d-1} $$
and the last integral equals
$$ \int_{(0,+\infty)^{d-1}}\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-(x_2+\ldots+x_d)}\right)\,d\mu_{d-1}=\int_{(0,1)^{d-1}}\frac{\text{Li}_2(v_2\cdots v_d)}{v_2\cdots v_d}\,dv_2\cdot dv_d$$
or
$$ \int_{(0,1)^{d-2}}\frac{\text{Li}_3(v_3\cdots v_d)}{v_3\cdots v_d}dv_3\cdots dv_d = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{Li}_d(w)}{w}\,dw=\text{Li}_{d+1}(1)=\color{red}{\zeta(d+1)}.$$

With the same technique we have:
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)^d}\frac{d\mu_d}{e^{x_1+\ldots+x_d}-1} = \text{Li}_d(1)=\color{red}{\zeta(d)}.$$

Comment: @FelixMarin: but the OP wants to integrate a vector, hence we have to consider $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\color{red}{x}\,dx\,dy}{e^{x+y}-1}=\zeta(3).$$

Comment: Or maybe I just interpreted $d^d\vec{r}$ the wrong way, i.e. as $d^d(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$. In any case, the approach works in both cases.

Comment: @FelixMarin: all right, I am going to add the alternative version too.

Answer (score 5):

Expand the integrand in a geometric series
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{1}{e^{x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_d}-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-k(x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_d)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-kx_1}\cdot e^{-kx_2}\cdot\ldots \cdot e^{-kx_{{d}}}.
\end{equation*}
For $d \ge 2$ the multiple integral over $V$  is given by
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx_1}\, dx_1\right)^{d} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^d} = \zeta(d).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left.\int_{\large\left[0,\infty\right)^{d}}
{\dd^{d}\vec{r} \over \expo{x_{1} + \cdots + x_{d}} - 1}\,
\right\vert_{\ d\ \geq\ 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{\large\left[0,\infty\right)^{d}}
\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\braces{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}\exp\pars{\bracks{z - x_{1} - \cdots - x_{d}}s}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
{\dd z \over \expo{z} - 1}}\dd^{d}\vec{r}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \expo{z} - 1}
\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}\expo{zs}
\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-xs}\,\dd x}^{d}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd z =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \expo{z} - 1}
\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}{\expo{zs} \over s^{d}}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \expo{z} - 1}{z^{d - 1} \over \pars{d - 1}!}\,\dd z =
{1  \over \pars{d - 1}!}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{d - 1}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1  \over \pars{d - 1}!}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{d - 1}! \over \pars{n + 1}^{d}} =
\bbx{\zeta\pars{d}}
\end{align}